# Why I can't find the button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#mount_0_0_sG > div > div > div > div.bdao358l.om3e55n1.g4tp4svg > div > div > div > div.alzwoclg.cqf1kptm.p1t2w4gn.fawcizw8.om3e55n1.g4tp4svg > section > main > div > header > section > div._aa_m > div._ab8w._ab94._ab99._ab9f._ab9k._ab9p._abb3._abcm > div > div > button"}
(Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.125)

I wanted to make an instagram bot, and when I try to subscribe using XPATH, CSS selector eth I get this message. I tried different methods with TAG_NAME and so on, but nothing helps

```
import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time


file = open("Bot.txt")
username_list = []
password_list = []
ind = 0

lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if ind % 2 == 0:
        if line.strip() == "":
            break
        else:
            username_list.append(line.strip())
            ind += 1
    else:
        password_list.append(line.strip())
        ind += 1


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/danylakopeika/PycharmProjects/"
                                                        "InstagramBot/chromedriver")
url = "https://www.instagram.com"

time.sleep(5)
browser.get(url)
login_inst = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "username")
login_inst.send_keys(username_list[0])
time.sleep(2)
password_inst = browser.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
password_inst.send_keys(password_list[0])

password_inst.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(5)
name = "danyla787"
try:
    browser.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{name}/")
    time.sleep(5)
    subscription = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mount_0_0_sG > div > div > div > div.bdao358l.om3e55n1.g4tp4svg > div > div > div > div.alzwoclg.cqf1kptm.p1t2w4gn.fawcizw8.om3e55n1.g4tp4svg > section > main > div > header > section > div._aa_m > div._ab8w._ab94._ab99._ab9f._ab9k._ab9p._abb3._abcm > div > div > button").click()
    time.sleep(5)
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
    browser.close()
    browser.quit()
```

Comment: Please show use the part of the HTML page with the button you are trying to find

Comment: I need a follow button on instagram

Comment: I need to see the element so I can know its attributes and where it is located.

Comment: Here is the link to the account, I need a subscribe button. https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/